# GZIP for CSS and JS dosen't work in Google Chrome, but does in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, header, compression, gzip

I have recently figured out how to enable GZIP (or Deflate) on my WAMP server that I will be using to serve my intranet application.

However, when testing in Google Chrome I see that the PHP file is compressed but Javascript files and CSS are not. The Response header shows that it is not compressed and Google Pagespeed confirms this.

Firefox on the other hand recives all files with compression without a problem.

Here are the headers for the main CSS file as an example:

**Google Chrome**

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:48:43 GMT
Content-Length: 6533
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 00:42:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.10
ETag: "a00000001509b-1985-4c50ff04b26ef"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/css
Accept-Ranges: bytes

200 OK
```

**Firefox**

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:33:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.10
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 00:42:33 GMT
Etag: "a00000001509b-1985-4c50ff04b26ef"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1273
Content-Type: text/css

200 OK
```

Is this a problem with my WAMP setup, code, or is it just Google Chrome?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google chrome does support JS/CSS gzip.

```
Request URL:http://d1o7y22ifnbryp.cloudfront.net/static/7793/css/all.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:d1o7y22ifnbryp.cloudfront.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5
```

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=604800
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:17933
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 18 Jul 2012 15:43:46 GMT
ETag:"805dc-19c87-4c4a305735340"
Expires:Wed, 25 Jul 2012 15:43:46 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 12 Jul 2012 14:45:57 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Amazon)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

I think the problem should be in apache configuration.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you have any idea where I would change this? It's quite an obscure problem. Thank you.

Comment: I am researching the same problem...I know Chrome supports it but I still get the same recommendation in Chrome Developer tools with regards to my CSS and HTML & JS (All fine in Firefox) Will write back if I figure it out.

Comment: @adam-asdf I know it's quite an old question but do you know more about this issue? I'm also facing it..